# forceCommunity:notifications for lighting web components

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-notification

I would like to know whether there is `forceCommunity:notifications` equivalent for `lighting web components`

Or at least how to subscribe for `custom notifications` using `lightning web component` would be very helpful.

Comment: You need an Aura component to wrap your LWC generally force: name space functions not supported in LWC you need an AURA wrapper to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need an Aura wrapper to do this

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout" access="global" description="Sample Custom Theme Layout">
    <forceCommunity:notifications/>
<!-- CALL LWC  COMPONENT -->
    <c:lwc />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: This is still using `<forceCommunity:notifications />` in Aura. I want to subscribe to custom notification inside lwc.